# Amazon S3 bucket folder turns private after new upload

Tags: amazon-web-services

I made my bucket folder public on Amazon, but after I collectstatic or simply uploading a new image. The folder will turn private, and I have to manually "right click" "make public" again...

This is very frustrating , I tried to look at Amazon documentation but without further help.

Answer (score 0):

To make all contents within an Amazon S3 bucket public:

- Select the bucket
- In the **Permissions** tab, select **Block Public Access**
- Turn OFF the two options that mention "Bucket Policies"
- **Add a Bucket Policy** to the bucket, such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This will automatically grant `GetObject` permission to every object, which effectively makes the bucket public.